# Python's Basemap doesn't align with correct coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, module, matplotlib-basemap

I have a `.dat` file containing a list of coordinates (~100k) and a temperature at each coordinate. It has a structure like this:

```
  -59.083  -26.583    0.2
  -58.417  -26.250    0.6
  -58.412  -26.417    0.4
   ...
```

To visually display the temperature ranges, I created a numpy array and plotted the datasets using the Basemap module for Python. The code I wrote is the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np 

m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.15)

data = np.loadtxt('gridly.dat')

xcoordlist = []
ycoordlist = []
tempvallist = []

for i in data:
    xcoord = i[0]
    ycoord = i[1]
    tempval = i[2]
    xcoord2 = xcoord*111139   #<--- Multiplying converts each coordinate's degrees to meters)
    ycoord2 = ycoord*111139
    xcoordlist.append(xcoord2)
    ycoordlist.append(ycoord2)
    tempvallist.append(tempval)

xco = np.array(xcoordlist)
yco = np.array(ycoordlist)
tval = np.array(tempvallist)

gridsize = 100
m.hexbin(yco, xco, C=tval, gridsize=gridsize)

cb = m.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

When I plot the data, I'm getting almost exactly what I want, however, the hexagonal heatmap is offset for some reason, giving me the following chart:
[image]

I've been searching online for what might be wrong but unfortunately couldn't find answers or troubleshoot. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of digging around, I finally figured it out! What was wrong with my code was that I was trying to manually convert the geographic coordinates into point coordinates for the displaying chart (by multiplying by 111139).

While the logic for doing this makes sense, I believe this process broke down when I began to plot the data onto different kinds of charts (i.e. orthogonal, miller projection etc.) because the different projections/charts will have different point coordinates (kind of like how the pixel locations on your computer screen may not align with the pixel locations on a different computer screen).

Instead, the Basemap module has a built-in function that will convert real-world coordinates into coordinates that can be plotted on the chart, for you: `m(x, y)`.

So, the improved and correct script would be:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np 

m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.15)

data = np.loadtxt('gridly.dat')

xcoordlist = []
ycoordlist = []
tempvallist = []

for i in data:
    lat = i[0]
    lon = i[1]
    tempval = i[2]
    xpt, ypt = m(lon, lat)
    xcoordlist.append(xpt)
    ycoordlist.append(ypt)
    tempvallist.append(tempval)

xco = np.array(xcoordlist)
yco = np.array(ycoordlist)
tval = np.array(tempvallist)

gridsize = 100
m.hexbin(xco, yco, C=tval, gridsize=gridsize)

cb = m.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

As you can see where it says `xpt, ypt = m(lon, lat)`, the function converts the real world longitudes (`lon`) and latitudes (`lat`) from the `.dat` file into pottable points. Hope this helps anyone else that may have this problem in the future!